# parsing JSONArray to JSONObject and get String to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, json

I want to get **JSONArray** to **String[]**.
In my code there is no error, but when I compile in logcat error refers to line:

```
detail[i] =
            "NAMA SIM       : "+jsonMain.optString("nama_pengendara").toString()+"\n"+
            "IDENTITAS      : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "NO.IDENTITAS   : "+jsonMain.optString("no_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "PELANGGARAN    : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_pelanggaran").toString()+"\n"+
            "--------------------------------";
```

`detail[]` is `String[]`, and `info_p` is JSONArray
This is my full code contain error wile compile:

```
public class InfoPelanggaranActivity extends Activity{
private static final String TAG = InfoPelanggaranActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
public static JSONArray info_p;//delegated isi response
ListView _lv_detail;
Button _btn_gotoAdd;
String[] detail;
int arrayLength;
ArrayList<String> detailList;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "Start onCreate InfoPelanggaranActivity");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_infopelanggaran);

    _lv_detail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_detail);
    _btn_gotoAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gotoAdd);
    _btn_gotoAdd.setOnClickListener(new ClickKeAdd());
    setDetails();
}

private String[] setDetails() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arrayLength = info_p.length();
    for(int i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++){
        Log.v(TAG, "Start setDetails(), for Index: "+i);
        JSONObject jsonMain = info_p.optJSONObject(i);
        detail[i] = new String[]{
                "NAMA SIM       : "+jsonMain.optString("nama_pengendara").toString()+"\n"+
                "IDENTITAS      : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
                "NO.IDENTITAS   : "+jsonMain.optString("no_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
                "PELANGGARAN    : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_pelanggaran").toString()+"\n"+
                "--------------------------------"};                    
    }
    Log.w(TAG, "detail[i]: "+detail.length);
    detailList = new ArrayList<String>();
    detailList.addAll(Arrays.asList(detail));
    //
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_infopelanggaran,detailList);
    _lv_detail.setAdapter(listAdapter);     
    return detail;
}
public class ClickKeAdd implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(InfoPelanggaranActivity.this,AddPelanggaranActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);           
    }

}
```

}

And this is the **EXCEPTION**:

```
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.peti/com.peti.InfoPelanggaranActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at com.peti.InfoPelanggaranActivity.setDetails(InfoPelanggaranActivity.java:54)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at com.peti.InfoPelanggaranActivity.onCreate(InfoPelanggaranActivity.java:40)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-30 18:41:58.226: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     ... 11 more
```

Why this happened ?
why I can not fill the details []?
Somebody help me please..

Comment: What is arrayLength? Is it the length of detail?

Comment: arrayLength is length of info_p, info_p is JSONArray.

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: why i can't fill detail[] ?

Comment: As to the exception, that occurs on line 54.  Which line is line 54???

Comment: @HotLicks: line 54 is **detail[]=**

Comment: So, what does your testing reveal as to which value is null on that line?

Comment: @HotLicks: I think, error at the time of filling the **detail[]**, but i don't know why.., can you tell me why?

Comment: What does your **TESTING** tell you about what is null on that line?  Ie, when you added println statements to print out the values, or stopped at that line in a debugger and examined the values, what did you see?

Comment: @HotLicks have not values of **detail[]** only error

Comment: You've got the `detail` array itself, and several other references (pointers) in that statement, any one of which could be null.  It's up to you, with your available debugging facilities, to figure out which one is null.  This is basic debugging.  (Just glancing at the code, it's probably `detail` that is null, but I haven't studied it closely.)

Comment: can tell me by code? please @HotLicks

Comment: Obviously, one of the `optString` invocations returned `null` and you are trying to invoke `toString()` on it. Note that all these `toString()` invocations are obsolete. When concatenating Strings, other values are automatically converted to `String` whereas `null` is converted to `"null"` (unlike explicit invocations of `toString()`).

Comment: yess, i will learn more from what you give. pleasee @HotLicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it...

```
detail[i] = new String[]{
                "NAMA SIM       : "+jsonMain.optString("nama_pengendara").toString()+"\n"+
                "IDENTITAS      : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
                "NO.IDENTITAS   : "+jsonMain.optString("no_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
                "PELANGGARAN    : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_pelanggaran").toString()+"\n"+
                "--------------------------------"};
```

this was your line 54

here you're creating String Array using new operator of size 1 , as there is no comma seperator
i.e.

```
new String[]{
            "NAMA SIM       : "+jsonMain.optString("nama_pengendara").toString()+"\n"+
            "IDENTITAS      : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "NO.IDENTITAS   : "+jsonMain.optString("no_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "PELANGGARAN    : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_pelanggaran").toString()+"\n"+
            "--------------------------------"};
```

and try to assign it into a String called **detail[i]**
This type of type conversion can't be automatically done.

now,the solution is ..after `arrayLength = info_p.length();`
add `detail=new String[arrayLength]`

and inside for loop change

```
detail[i] = new String[]{
            "NAMA SIM       : "+jsonMain.optString("nama_pengendara").toString()+"\n"+
            "IDENTITAS      : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "NO.IDENTITAS   : "+jsonMain.optString("no_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "PELANGGARAN    : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_pelanggaran").toString()+"\n"+
            "--------------------------------"};
```

to

```
detail[i] = "NAMA SIM       : "+jsonMain.optString("nama_pengendara").toString()+"\n"+
            "IDENTITAS      : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "NO.IDENTITAS   : "+jsonMain.optString("no_identitas").toString()+"\n"+
            "PELANGGARAN    : "+jsonMain.optString("jenis_pelanggaran").toString()+"\n"+
            "--------------------------------";
```